# Is it possible to use CASE with WHERE?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to do this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN field = true THEN one * another ELSE one END as case_field 
FROM table WHERE case_field >= 9000
```

and receive an error that case_field doesn't exist.

Is it possible to do this without duplicating CASE ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like PostgresSQL supports [derived tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT CASE WHEN field = true THEN one * another ELSE one END as case_field 
FROM table 
) AS derived
WHERE case_field >= 9000
```

You might want to check that it doesn't have any adverse affect on the execution plan.

Comment: @Milen - Cheers for updating the link!

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     SELECT 
        CASE WHEN field = true THEN one * another
        ELSE one
        END as case_field 
        FROM table
     ) a
 WHERE a.case_field >= 9000
```

Comment: This is not a temporary table, it's a subquery.